# trimming a string in a JSTL expression

Tags: string, jstl, trim

I have the following line in a JSP page:

```
<c:if test="${postAuditBean.postAudit.authority == authority.value}">
```

I would like change this comparison to first trim leading and trailing spaces from both the left and right hand expressions prior to comparison... as in something like this:

```
<c:if test="${trim(postAuditBean.postAudit.authority) == trim(authority.value)}">
```

I tried this:

```
<c:if test="${fn:trim(postAuditBean.postAudit.authority) == fn:trim(authority.value)}">
```

which generated a parsing error in the JSP page.

Can anyone tell me how to trim blanks from JSTL subexpressions?

Comment: In the future please post the exact error message as well. Never say alone "I got error". Interpreting error messages is very important because they actually tell something about the cause of the problem.

Comment: Typo see self-answer, user deleted so probably also voting ring.

Answer (score 1):

Refer : [JSTL fn:trim() Function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_trim.htm)